# Inline Formatting Content in JSON files

Tags: css, json, xml

We author our documentation in XML and package it to a JSON file to render it on a tablet. But, the  basic inline formatting (bold, italics, superscript, and subscript) does not get converted to the JSON. It is plain text. Is there a way to get the tablet/JSON file to include the formatting? Like, attaching a CSS or something? If yes, then what's the effort?

Comment: Questions are expected to be [a minimal, complete and verifiable example (mcve), or a minimal, workable example (mwe)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please, try to add details to your question (xml, json samples or snippets, what gets lost, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, XML does not include any information about formatting either, would need to look at an example on how you include that information in XML, and maybe do something similar in json.

You can use XSLT to transform XML to JSON.

There is already a stylesheet to get you started at: [XSLTJSON: Transforming XML to JSON using XSLT](https://github.com/bramstein/xsltjson)